# C# Webkit GetElementById Click

Tags: c#, dom, webkit, click, getelementbyid

I just have a simple question.
How can I click a button in Webkit?

I have this code for the normal webbrowser:

```
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
        document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

How does this work for Webkit and I have also this one, which doesn't work either:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("class") == "bla")
            {
                element.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use 
`webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(document.getElementById('id').click())`